# How to re run Macros again based on the latest cell values

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have these sets of Macros that force rows to hide and unhide based on cell value changes, it can run as intended but the rows may unwantedly be hidden/unhidden from time to time due to the sequencing of the macros I think. Is there a way to re run the all the macros again based on the latest value in the target cells? Where I do not have to go back to every individual cell to trigger the value to run the macro. I have searching the web and trying out what I thought were possible solutions but just couldn't get it to work. I really deeply appreciate any help or advice given!
My macros current macros is as below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Activate
        If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C8"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = "A": Rows("54").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Rows("61").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Rows("77").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Rows("93").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Rows("109").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Rows("129").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case Is = "B": Rows("54").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("61").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("77").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("93").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("109").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("129").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "C": Rows("54").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Rows("61").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Rows("77").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Rows("93").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Rows("109").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Rows("129").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End Select
End If
        If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C8"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = "B": Sheets("Proforma Inv").Visible = True
        Case Else
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Visible = False
        End Select
End If
        If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C9"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = "Debug", "Soshi": Rows("55").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("41").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("48").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("62").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("39").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("46").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("53").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("60").EntireRow.Hidden = True

        Case Else
                       Rows("55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("41").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("48").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("55").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("62").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("39").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("46").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("53").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("60").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End Select
End If
        If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C52"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = "1": Rows("72:119").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Rows("57:60").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("62:71").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("44:64").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("38:40").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("42:43").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("22:23").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("39:40").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("56:57").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("73:74").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("42:62").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("36:38").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("40:41").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "2": Rows("88:119").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Rows("57:60").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("62:76").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("78:87").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("51:64").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("38:40").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("42:47").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("49:50").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("22:23").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("39:40").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("56:57").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("73:74").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("49:62").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("36:38").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("40:45").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("47:48").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "3": Rows("104:119").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Rows("57:60").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("62:76").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("78:92").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("94:103").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("58:64").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("38:40").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("42:47").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("49:54").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("56:57").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("22:23").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("39:40").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("56:57").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("73:74").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("56:62").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("36:38").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("40:45").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("47:52").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("54:55").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "4": Rows("57:60").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("62:76").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("78:92").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("94:108").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("110:119").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("38:40").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("42:47").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("49:54").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("56:61").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("63:64").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("22:23").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("39:40").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("56:57").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("73:74").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("36:38").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("40:45").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("47:52").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("54:59").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("61:62").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End Select
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: `Range(Target.Address)` is redundant: just `Target`.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually a good idea to move the bulk of your code into a separate sub and call that from the event handler: then you can also call it from other places

Regular module:

```
Sheet1.SyncVis
```

Sheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     CheckVis Target
End Sub

Sub SyncVis()
    Me.CheckVis Range("C8")
    Me.CheckVis Range("C52")
End Sub


Private Sub CheckVis(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim tf As Boolean
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C8"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        With Range("A54,A61,A77,A93,A109,A129").EntireRow
            Select Case Target.Value
                Case "A", "C": .Hidden = True
                Case "B": .Hidden = False
            End Select
        End With
        Sheets("Proforma Inv").Visible = Target.Value = "B"
    End If

    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C9"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        tf = Target.Value = "Debug" or Target.Value = "Soshi" 
        Rows("55").EntireRow.Hidden = tf
        Sheets("Inv").Range("A41,A48,A55,A62").EntireRow.Hidden = tf
        Sheets("Proforma Inv").Range("A39,A46,A53,A60").EntireRow.Hidden = tf 
    End If

    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C52"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = "1": Range("A72:A119,A57:A60,A62:A71").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("44:64").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("38:40").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("42:43").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("22:23").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("39:40").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("56:57").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("73:74").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("42:62").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("36:38").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("40:41").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "2": Rows("88:119").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Rows("57:60").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("62:76").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("78:87").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("51:64").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("38:40").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("42:47").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("49:50").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("22:23").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("39:40").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("56:57").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("73:74").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("49:62").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("36:38").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("40:45").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("47:48").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "3": Rows("104:119").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Rows("57:60").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("62:76").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("78:92").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("94:103").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("58:64").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("38:40").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("42:47").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("49:54").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("56:57").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("22:23").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("39:40").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("56:57").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("73:74").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("56:62").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("36:38").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("40:45").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("47:52").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("54:55").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is = "4": Rows("57:60").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("62:76").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("78:92").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("94:108").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Rows("110:119").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("38:40").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("42:47").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("49:54").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("56:61").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Inv").Rows("63:64").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("22:23").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("39:40").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("56:57").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("PL").Rows("73:74").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("36:38").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("40:45").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("47:52").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("54:59").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                       Sheets("Proforma Inv").Rows("61:62").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End Select
End If
End Sub
```